# Disabling and Enabling of buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi guys i am new in JavaScript language, question is on page run button(1) should be disabled and another should be clickable, after click of button(2) enable the button(1)
kindly help me please...

Comment: might as well paste your code here so we can help you better

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How To Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code it will work,That is when the page is loaded the button1 will be disabled and button2 will be enabled and on click of button2 button1 will be enabled

**In JS:**

```
$( "#button1" ).prop( "disabled", true );

function buttonClick(){
$( "#button1" ).prop( "disabled", false );
}
```

**In HTML:**

```
<input type="button" id="button2" onclick="buttonClick()">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<!-- Include jQuery library -->
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- Your css -->
<style>
  #button1, #button2 {
    width: 70px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  #button1.disabled {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    color: #808080;
  }
</style>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

     $('#button2').on('click', function(){

        $('#button1').removeClass('disabled');
        $('#button1').on('click', function(){
          // Your button 1 function
        });

     });

  });
</script>

<!-- Content -->
<body>
  <div id="button1" class="disabled">Button 1</div>
  <div id="button2">Button 2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope I answered your question.

Answer (score -1):

add the following css to the button:
pointer-events:none;

if u want to enable thw button , add following css:

pointer-events:defau